# Rails 3: Using a 'for' statement to create a set of radio buttons, how to set the first button value to true?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

I'm using

```
<% for category in Category.find(:all) %>
<%= radio_button_tag "post[category_id]", category.id, post.category_id == 
         category.id %>
```

This creates a set of radio buttons for all my categories but none of the buttons are set to true by default. How can I make the first button set to 'true'?

Comment: Are you sure `post.category_id` returns an id that belongs to a category? May be they are different or returning nil.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it works out of the box but you could try something like that :

```
<% Category.find(:all).each_with_index do |category, index| %> %>
<%= radio_button_tag "post[category_id]", category.id, (index == 0) %>
```

Comment: Is there a `checked` param for `radio_button_tag` helper? And the order of params seems to be wrong. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag

Comment: my bad, edited my answer accordingly. this should make the first radio button checked by default as the OP wants

Comment: You edited it, now this will check the first radio button in the list. But it seems that he wants to check the one that matches with the `post.category_id`, like to show the category that was selected for this specific product.